# sentiment package installation from local zip file issue

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to find a way to install sentiment package in R for performing sentiment analysis.
I searched in all d repositories but it isn't available.I am trying to manually install sentiment_0.2.tar file from local directory but i get this:

> Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
>     cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
>   2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
>     cannot open compressed file 'sentiment_0.2.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

How do i resolve this problem? any valuable suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: I would recommend to do this: `install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL, type="source")`. This should allow you to select the file itself and install the package subsequently. Also, please note that the package version may not be compatible with the current R version on your machine.

Comment: Also, did you unzip the file? You should leave it in the `gz` form when installing locally.

Comment: @Abdou: Thank you so much. This worked like a charm. I was able to successfully install the package.

Comment: @MrFlick: i haven't unzipped the file. That was the name of the package. It is with .gz extension. Anyways its working now.

Comment: @Neha, I am glad it worked! I will write it as the answer and you can accept it so this question can be marked answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL, type="source")
```

This should allow you to select the file itself and install the package subsequently. Also, please note that the package version may not be compatible with the current R version on your machine.

Thanks!